# Cannot install gulp-angular

Tags: angularjs, gulp, yo

I am using gulp-angular for the first time, and am following this blog: http://www.angularonrails.com/how-to-wire-up-ruby-on-rails-and-angularjs-as-a-single-page-application-gulp-version/

When I run through the install questions, it just bombs out, on Karma.

I'm on ubuntu 14 in a Vagrant box, node v0.10.37, npm 2.7.5

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
fluent@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/fluent/client$ yo gulp-angular myapp
.
.
? Which version of Angular do you want? 1.3.x (latest)
? Which Angular's modules would you want to have? (ngRoute and ngResource will be addressed after) angular-animate.js (enable animation features),  angular-cookies.js (handle cookie management), angular-touch.js (for mobile development), angular-sanitize.js (to securely parse and manipulate HTML)
? Would you need jQuery or perhaps Zepto? None (Angular will use its own jqLite)
? Would you like to use a REST resource library? None, $http is enough!
? Would you like to use a router ? ngRoute, the official router
? Which UI framework do you want? Bootstrap, the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework
? How do you want to implements your Bootstrap components? Angular UI Bootstrap, Bootstrap components written in pure AngularJS by the AngularUI Team
? Which CSS preprocessor do you want? Sass (Node), Node.js binding to libsass, the C version of the popular stylesheet preprocessor, Sass.
? Which JS preprocessor do you want? None, I like to code in standard JavaScript.
? Which html template engine would you want? None, I like to code in standard HTML.
Template processing error on file karma.conf.js

events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
AssertionError: Trying to copy from a source that does not exist:     /usr/lib/node_modules/generator-gulp-angular/app/templates/karma.conf.js
at EditionInterface.exports._copySingle (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-  gulp-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/mem-fs- editor/actions/copy.js:44:3)
```

Some additional information, not really sure what to make of this, there *is* a _karma.conf.js file

```
myapp@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-gulp-angular/app/templates$ ls
_bower.json      e2e          gulp          _.jshintrc      _package.json         src        tslint.json
coffeelint.json  _.gitignore  _gulpfile.js  _karma.conf.js  protractor.conf.js  _tsd.json
```

**EDIT**

I have had to use **sudo** for all npm commands. Is this normal?

**EDIT 2**
https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular/issues/470

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the github issue, deleting the reference to **karma.conf.js** from **app/files.json** did the job.

I guess there will be an official fix at some point.

Comment: Looks like there's been some recent activity on [the GitHub issue](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular/issues/470). Maybe v0.11.0 of generator-gulp-angular fixes it?

Comment: @JasonSwett according to the release notes it has been fixed.